# Excel sheet name issues for ADODB queries

Tags: excel, vba, oledb

I have been writing some macros using ADODB queries to retrieve data from other workbooks, using Excel 2013.  During testing an 'invalid bracketing' error appeared on some cases and with trial and error, I came to the conclusion that ADODB could not handle sheetnames containing ***a dot followed by a space***. In other words:

```
XYZ S.à r.l. -12.2017  -> error   
XYZ S.à r.l -12.2017   -> works ok (dot before space is deleted)
XYZ S.à r.l.-12.2017   -> works ok (space after dot is deleted)
```

Of course in the query the sheet name is surronded by backticks :-)
The error msg -2147217900 is; Invalid bracketing of name 'XYZ S.à r.l. -12.2017$A9:H49'

My question is: do you know any other similar issue that I should track ? Is that documented anywhere ?

---

update: the generated SQL statement (but again, this has been tested successfully in a number of other workbooks, and I managed to make it work by renaming the 1st of the 2 worksheetss involved as described above)

```
select cstr(pr.reference), pr.[name],null, pr.item, pr.country, pr.currency, pr.maturity, pr.sector 
 from [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=\\mydomain.com\someLongPath\XYZ S.à r.l. - 12.2017 - reviewed - MACRO TESTING.xlsx].`XYZ S.à r.l. -12.2017$A9:H49` pr
 where  cstr(pr.reference) not in (select cur.reference from [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=\\mydomain.com\someLongPath\KB Sarl - 01.2018 to 03.2018 - MACRO TESTING.xlsx].`TB - 03.2018$A9:H51`cur ) 
 and pr.item is not null
```

This query gets the data from Previous list whose Reference is absent from Current list. Previous and Current lists are normally in different workbooks.

Comment: I'm not convinced space-dot that alone is the issue. I'd be interested to see your related code.There's disagreement over whether backticks are a good idea to use at all. I'd opt to keep it simple instead of storing data in the tab name. More [here](https://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/seven-characters-you-cant-use-in-worksheet-names).  Also in your error `'XYZ S.à r.l. -12.2017$A9:H49'`, maybe the quotes are part of the error message... but those aren't backticks. :)   Oddly, the word `history` is not allowed in worksheet names.

Comment: @ashleedawg thanks for your reply.The quotes you mention are not part of the name. I will update the question with the generated SQL statement. Also note that I have little or no control on the tab names: I wrote the macro as an add-in and the business uses it on existing workbooks. I can just give them some minimal requirements for their data files.

Comment: have you tried `[XYZ S.à r.l. -12.2017]$A9:H49`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav not here, but I remember trying to use that in another macro and it would crash with the dots. That's why I switched to the backticks, which work great, except for that 'dot space' exception.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51677080/78522

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question:

I came to the conclusion that ADODB could not handle sheetnames containing a dot followed by a space ("`.` ").
Consequently I just added a check for this.

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with an issue that is exactly the same. One possible solution is to replace `.`+ <kbd>Space</kbd> with `#` + <kbd>Space</kbd> as in `TableName=Replace(Tablename,". ","# ")`. Apparently `#` is good enough for Access. This suggestion comes [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21490432/8597922).